# How to output results of 'msa' package in R to fasta

Tags: r, alignment, bioinformatics, fasta

I am using the [R package `msa`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/msa/inst/doc/msa.pdf), a core [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/install/) package, for multiple sequence alignment. Within `msa`, I am using the MUSCLE alignment algorithm to align protein sequences.

```
library(msa)
myalign <- msa("test.fa", method=c("Muscle"), type="protein",verbose=FALSE)
```

The test.fa file is a standard fasta as follows (truncated, for brevity):

```
>sp|P31749|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC
MSDVAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWRPRYFLL
>sp|P31799|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC
MSVVAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWRFLL
```

When I run the code on the file, I get:

```
 MUSCLE 3.8.31   

Call:
   msa("test.fa", method = c("Muscle"), type = "protein", verbose = FALSE)

MsaAAMultipleAlignment with 2 rows and 480 columns
    aln 
[1] MSDVAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWRPRYFLL
[2] MSVVAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWR---FLL
Con MS?VAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWR???FLL
```

As you can see, a very reasonable alignment.

I want to write the gapped alignment, preferably without the consensus sequence (e.g., Con row), to a fasta file. So, I want:

```
>sp|P31749|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC
MSDVAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWRPRYFLL
>sp|P31799|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC
MSVVAIVKEGWLHKRGEYIKTWR---FLL
```

I checked the `msa` help, and the package does not seem to have a built in method for writing out to any file type, fasta or otherwise.

The [seqinr package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/3.3-3) looks somewhat promising, because maybe it could read this output as an msf format, albeit a weird one. However, `seqinr` seems to need a file read in as a starting point. I can't even save this using `write(myalign, ...)`.

Comment: You really should stop capitalizing package names that aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you ought to follow the examples in the help pages that show input with a specific `read` function first, then work with the alignment:

```
mySeqs <- readAAStringSet("test.fa")
myAlignment <- msa(mySeqs)
```

Then the `rownames` function will deliver the sequence names:

```
 rownames(myAlignment)
[1] "sp|P31749|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC" "sp|P31799|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC"
```

(Not what you asked for but possibly useful in the future.) Then if you execute:

```
detail(myAlignment)   #function actually in Biostrings
```

.... you get a text file in interactive mode that you can save

```
2 29
sp|P31749|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC   MSDVAIVKEG WLHKRGEYIK TWRPRYFLL
sp|P31799|AKT1_HUMAN_RAC   MSVVAIVKEG WLHKRGEYIK TWR---FLL
```

If you wnat to try hacking a function for which you can get a file written in code, then look at the Biostrings `detail` function code that is being used

```
> showMethods( f= 'detail')
Function: detail (package Biostrings)
x="ANY"
x="MsaAAMultipleAlignment"
    (inherited from: x="MultipleAlignment")
x="MultipleAlignment"

showMethods( f= 'detail', classes='MultipleAlignment', includeDefs=TRUE)
Function: detail (package Biostrings)
x="MultipleAlignment"
function (x, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (x, invertColMask = FALSE, hideMaskedCols = TRUE) 
    {
        FH <- tempfile(pattern = "tmpFile", tmpdir = tempdir())
        .write.MultAlign(x, FH, invertColMask = invertColMask, 
            showRowNames = TRUE, hideMaskedCols = hideMaskedCols)
        file.show(FH)
    }
    .local(x, ...)
}
```

Comment: I am eternally grateful! The first option will do exactly what I want. I will also try to better understand the second choice as I move forward with this work. Finally, I will be more mindful of package name particulars in the future as I am sensitive to the fact that the names are specifically chosen to be as they are by the package authors.

Comment: Based on your helpful comments about Biostrings and the built in functions, I was able to find that there is also a built in function for saving as phylip format. It is, unsurprisingly, write.phylip(x, ...). Go figure! Thanks again!

Comment: I had seen that function as I was perusing the documentation, but it didn't seem an exact fit to your requirements. At the bottom of this page: https://rdrr.io/bioc/Biostrings/api/ you can find a more complete list of `write` functions from Biostrings.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a function:

```
alignment2Fasta <- function(alignment, filename) {
  sink(filename)

  n <- length(rownames(alignment))
  for(i in seq(1, n)) {
    cat(paste0('>', rownames(alignment)[i]))
    cat('\n')
    the.sequence <- toString(unmasked(alignment)[[i]])
    cat(the.sequence)
    cat('\n')  
  }

  sink(NULL)
}
```

Usage:

```
mySeqs <- readAAStringSet('test.fa')
myAlignment <- msa(mySeqs)
alignment2Fasta(myAlignment, 'out.fasta')
```

Comment: It's ridiculous that the people that developed `msa` didn't think of adding a small function that would simplify writing to file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [export.fasta](https://rdrr.io/cran/bios2mds/man/export.fasta.html) function from [bio2mds](https://rdrr.io/cran/bios2mds/) library.

`# reading of the multiple sequence alignment of human GPCRS in FASTA format:
aln <- import.fasta(system.file("msa/human_gpcr.fa", package = "bios2mds"))
export.fasta(aln)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your msa alignment first ("AAStringSet") into an "align" object first, and then export as fasta as follows:

```
library(msa)

library(bios2mds)

mysequences <-readAAStringSet("test.fa")

alignCW  <- msa(mysequences)

#https://rdrr.io/bioc/msa/man/msaConvert.html

alignCW_as_align <- msaConvert(alignCW, "bios2mds::align")

export.fasta(alignCW_as_align, outfile = "test_alignment.fa", ncol = 60, open = "w")
```